# Two Ruby Classes Depending on Each Other

Tags: ruby, dependencies, circular-dependency, single-responsibility-principle

I'm currently having a little trouble managing my dependencies whilst trying to maintain Single Responsibility and OOD.

I have a master class call Menu:

```
class Menu

  def initialize(dishes:, prices:, menuFormatter:)
    @dishes = dishes
    @prices = prices
    @menuFormatter = menuFormatter
  end

  def avaliable_dishes
    dishes.dishes_list
  end

  def dish_prices
    prices.prices_list
  end

  def formatted_menu
    menuFormatter.formatted_menu
  end

  private

  attr_reader :dishes, :prices, :menuFormatter
end
```

Now, the way I see it is that the Menu class pulls together all of the different parts of the menu, and supplies it to the hypothetical customer. The dishes are handled, updated, removed in their own class (Dishes), the prices are done in the same way (Prices) and then there is a separate class MenuFormatter who's responsibility is to take the contents of the Menu and turn it into a nicely arranged menu. Lines 17 to 19 are where my MenuFormatter class is called into action but my problem arises within that class:

```
class MenuFormatter

  def avaliable_dishes
    menu.avaliable_dishes
  end

  def dish_prices
    menu.dish_prices
  end

  def format_menu
    #Loop through dishes and prices and arrange them.
  end
end
```

The error i'm now faced with is that the MenuFormatter doesn't know what menu is because i've not defined it within the class. I'm unsure how to make my menu variable point to the instance of Menu so that it can have access to the dishes and prices.

I'd hoped not to give MenuFormatter access to Dishes or Prices as I feel that could lead to further coupling than necessary within my code.

Comment: Some feedback...1) I suggest MenuFormatter be a class nested in Menu. 2) I don't see anything wrong with both Menu and MenuFormattter being dependent on dishes and prices. They both have legitimate needs for them. 3) The MenuFormatter probably has no state and could be implemented as a Module instead of a Class, thereby communicating the statelessness. 4) I think you have a typo, you say "The error i'm *not* faced with".

Comment: Thanks @KeithBennett, I shall look into nested classes and Modules. very helpful, and thanks for spotting the typo.

For the dependencies, in this instance I do agree with you, they do both currently have legitimate needs for them. The actual purpose of the code is as a practice exercise in making the most changeable code I possibly can, with that in mind I'm inclined to keep my classes decoupled and inject as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing the instance of `menu` itself as an argument to the `format_menu` method:

```
def formatted_menu
  menuFormatter.formatted_menu(self)
end
```

Here, in the definition of an instance method of the `Menu` class, `self` refers to the instance of menu on which the `formatted_menu` method is called.

And then in `MenuFormatter`:

```
def formatted_menu(menu)
  # menu.dishes... 
  # menu.prices....
end
```